# Grouping in tcl

Tags: tcl, grouping

How to create grouping in tcl. I'm searching for long time. Help me to do that for example

```
set unique "arun samuel"
set all "arun abc1 abc2 abc3 arun abc4 abc5 abc6 arun abc7 abc8 abc9 samuel xyz1 xyz2 xyz3 samuel xyz4 xyz5 samuel xyz6"
```

I want the o/p like this:

arun:

abc1

abc2

...

abc8

samuel:

xyz1

xyz2

...

xyz6

I tried this code:

```
set unique "arun samuel"
set all "arun abc1 abc2 abc3 arun abc4 abc5 abc6 arun abc7 abc8 abc9 samuel xyz1 xyz2 xyz3 samuel xyz4 xyz5 samuel xyz6"

foreach f $all {
set id [lindex $unique [expr [lsearch $unique $f + ]]]
puts "Scrubber id is $unique"
puts "Scrubber id is $id"

}
```

But I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: How are you (not your code, _you_) determining where the boundaries are between groups?

Comment: I thought, it can be done by lsearch but I'm not sure that I'm going right way, so only I posted here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fairly simple. You loop over all, check if the current element is one of the "unique" elements, if yes, this is the current group, otherwise add the element to the current group.

```
set unique "arun samuel"
set all "arun abc1 abc2 abc3 arun abc4 abc5 abc6 arun abc7 abc8 abc9 samuel xyz1 xyz2 xyz3 samuel xyz4 xyz5 samuel xyz6"

set current {}
set result {}
foreach e $all {
    if {$e in $unique} {
        set current $e
    } else {
        dict lappend result $current $e
    }
}
dict for {group values} $result {
    puts "${group}: $values"
}
```

[Output](https://ideone.com/sl40GJ):

```
arun: abc1 abc2 abc3 abc4 abc5 abc6 abc7 abc8 abc9
samuel: xyz1 xyz2 xyz3 xyz4 xyz5 xyz6
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this problem is to use [array](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1032):

```
set unique "arun samuel"
set all "arun abc1 abc2 abc3 arun abc4 abc5 abc6 arun abc7 abc8 abc9 samuel xyz1 xyz2 xyz3 samuel xyz4 xyz5 samuel xyz6"

array set groups {}
foreach element $all {
    if {$element in $unique} {
        set key $element
    } else {
        lappend groups($key) $element
    }
}

puts $all
parray groups
```

The algorithm is simple:

1. Start with an empty array
2. For each element in the `all` list, if the element is in `unique`, then remember it as a key; otherwise, append that element to the array.

Note that you can access the grouping for *arun* as `$groups(arun)`.